# Media only screen doesn't work

Tags: css, frontend

I am having trouble with "media only screen" styling. It looks like that on my mobile phone (ip7):

[image]

My css code is like this, but it doesn't have any affect on the page look. I have put meta things in my html file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

#katalog {
    height: 10px;
}

#salon {
    width: 200px;
}
}
```

For example orginal #katalog style looks like this

```
position: relative;
width:50%;
height: 700px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

I was having troubles posting the html code using 'code option' that is added here, so I think 
[using jsfiddle is better](https://jsfiddle.net/fwofpcr4/)

My page hosted -> https://james0nerep.000webhostapp.com/#

Comment: Please go read [ask], and then present all the relevant info directly in your question, not as screenshots only.

Comment: What more can I add here if I really don't know what the problem is

Comment: Add relevant code that makes the problem reproducible. And while doing so, reduce the code as much as possible, trying to narrow it down to a minimal version that still shows the problem. Also, create a [mcve] out of it if at all possible, so that people can see the problem “live” and modify it.

Comment: You're missing a closing } from the end of the first code block you added. Not sure if that fixes the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Nah, it was fine in the original code. There are no errors shown so I suppose that the { or } are fine.

Comment: Add your HTML to your question

Comment: I have added everything in one place. I hope that it is gonna help.